# Use NSNotificationCenter to set ivars?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a relatively simple application. I have a UINavigationController and always have my mainViewController pushed on it. Occasionally I'll push on a settings and sub-settings controller. In my sub-settings controller, the user can make modifications to ivars in my mainViewController. Right now I have these ivars declared as properties and am setting them directly. I am using `self.navigationController.viewControllers[0]` to get a reference to the main controller then setting the properties. Is it better to use NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: Use `NSNotificationCenter`... **for what?**

Comment: You can pass the pointer on parent view controller to the details controller in init method. You can define some protocol f.e. detailsviewcontroller delegate, and retur value to delegate. There is many ways

Comment: Any time the user modifies settings in the sub-settings controller, ask NSNotificationCenter to broadcast a notification to mainController to tell it to change the ivars.

Comment: Why don't you create subsettingsdelegateprotocol ? And create @property (nonatomic, assign) Id  <subsettingsdelegateprotocol> delegate in subsettingsviewcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a very good design to have your settings controllers have any knowledge of your primary view controller. What happens when you add more functionality to your app in the future and more screens in the app need to deal with changes in any settings?

It is a far better design to separate the behavior. Your settings view controllers should update a "settings model" of some sort. The class representing this model should then be able to broadcast any changes. Using `NSNotificationCenter` for this is a good approach.

Now any class that might care about changes in settings can register for the appropriate notifications and act accordingly when there is a change.

This way you can have multiple view controllers or other classes that respond to settings changes and nothing in the settings code needs to care about any specific view controllers or how many there are.

Comment: Should I use NSNotificationCenter or delegates? Delegates seem better for 1 to 1 relations whereas notification center is better for 1 to many relations.

Comment: @user1802143 Delegates can only be used when there is one specific listener. Using notifications allows for any number of listeners (zero or more). Given that your app is likely to evolve over time and something like settings could affect multiple parts of the app, using notifications is probably the better choice for the long term.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine since you can easily get a references to your main view controller from your settings view controllers.  It's really just a matter of preference.

The real purpose of `NSNotificationCenter` is when multiple objects need to be notified of an event or where it's difficult to get a reference to the object you want to modify. `NSNotificationCenter` can also make your code cleaner and easier to modify.

For instance, if you change the design of your app in the future such as moving the settings view controllers to tabs rather than pushing them onto a navigation controller you might find it more difficult to modify your main view controller directly from them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to use `NSNotificationCenter` when you have disparate components in your app that would logically have no understanding of each other's API. However, where you are displaying a view for a sub-settings controller, it would be easy to have a settings object that you could just pass from the `mainViewController` to the `subSettingsViewController`. In your sub-settings view controller, in the `-viewWillDisappear:` memthod, ensure that all of the values have been saved to your settings object. Finally, in your main view controller's `-viewWillAppear:` method, you would just update the UI of the main view with the values in your settings object.

Here's some code to illustrate this:

**MainViewController.m**

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MySettings *settings;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SubSettingsViewController *subSettingsViewController;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (IBAction) showSubSettings: (id) sender {
    [self.subSettingsViewController setSettings: self.settings];
    //  Present 'subSettingsViewController'
}

- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    //  Set values from settings object for various text fields, UI controls, etc.
}
```

**SubSettingsViewController.h**

```
@interface SubSettingsViewController ()
@property MySettings *settings;
@end
```

**SubSettingsViewController.m**

```
@implementation SubSettingsViewController

- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
    //  Set values for the appropriate properties in 'self.settings'
    [self.settings setValue1: self.textField1.text];
}
```